# How to multiply dictionary keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I would like to multiply the keys of this dictionary by 2

```
d = {2: (1,2), 8: (2,4), 30: (10,3)}

for i in d.keys():
    print(i*2)

4
16
60
```

But `d` is still `{2: (1,2), 8: (2,4), 30: (10,3)}`

How can I get `d` to become `{4: (1,2), 16: (2,4), 60: (10,3)}` ?

Comment: This does not make any sense. Do you want the key to multiply with each value or just the first one?

Comment: see if the answer posted below helped? if it did, you may accept it by clicking on the tick sign beside it. cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want is:

Multiply each `key` with `2`. Not the square of it.

```
d = {2: (1,2), 8: (2,4), 30: (10,3)}
d = {k*2: v for (k, v) in d.items()}
print(d)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{4: (1, 2), 16: (2, 4), 60: (10, 3)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
d = {2: (1,2), 8: (2,4), 30: (10,3)}
d = {k**2: v for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

dictionary comprehension:

```
double = {k*2:v for (k,v) in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_d = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    new_d[k*2] = v
d = new_d
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d = dict((key*2, value) for (key, value) in d.items())
```